# How to build a Stackexchange-like search while typing in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, governorlimits, ajax, sosl

We have an internal defect tracker in Salesforce which should have much more of the charming features of Stackexchange.

One feature that I love the most is the live-search for duplicates while entering a new question.

Is there a way to implement such a search on hundreds of records in Salesforces? I have no experience SOSL but I guess this could be of great help for building this.

Has anyone build this or have seen tutorials on parts that I could need?

Comment: You may want to ask a more specific question; what you're describing is a pretty straightforward tie together of some ajax calls that read character input, a SOSL query or two, and a way of displaying the results to the user.  You may want to check out the jQuery documentation on their autocomplete support, which you may or may not want to use - but it also contains some examples reading character input and proactively searching via AJAX. I've integrated it with Visualforce many times, it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Andy Mahood has built something similar with [Autocomplete for Salesforce](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-9dEd5Sqv0), which you could draw inspiration from.

It's also natively available on the Idea object... sorta.
[image: search for duplicates]

Comment: If Salesforce.com used this for Ideas there must be someone how knows how to build this. Andy Mahoods solution doesn't seem to perform well, so i don't want to dig into it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic implementation.  Write it using javascript & remoting and it will probably be adequately fast.

vf:

```
<input type="text" id="search-box" value="" />
<br />
<ul id="duplicate-results">
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
var MIN_SEARCH_LENGTH = 10;

$(document).ready(function() {
  bindSearch();
});

function bindSearch() {
  $("input#search-box").keyup(searchForDuplicates);
}

function searchForDuplicates() {
  var currentValue = $.trim($(this).val());

  if(currentValue && currentValue > MIN_SEARCH_LENGTH) {
    MyController.searchForDuplicates(currentValue, function(result, event) {
      var $addTo = $('ul#duplicate-results');
      for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        $addTo.append('<li>' + result[i].name + '</li>');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

apex:

```
@RemoteAction
public static List<SObject> searchForDuplicates(String dupeName) {
  dupeName = '%' + dupeName + '%';
  return [SELECT Id, Name FROM SomeObject WHERE Name like :dupeName];
}
```

Comment: I think the Remoting architecture looks great. But the use of SOQL LIKE will restrict us to use "short" text fields, right. No chance to search in long text fields.

Comment: You could just alter my example to use a sosl search instead of a soql query.

Comment: BTW: The code like you posted it does not work. The way to call the remote action from Javascript ist different.

Comment: could this hit query limits if the user is doing a lot of typing/deleting?